# Update a .7z file in-place to turn on filename encryption?

Tags: encryption, archive

Does anyone know if it's possible to flip the switch on an existing .7z file to encrypt the filenames?

I have a large batch of files that are encrypted, but none of them have the filenames encrypted, and I'd like to turn that on.  Before I go the route of writing a script to extract and then re-archive each I was hoping someone knew of a simpler way to essentially flip the switch in-place?  I'm on Windows if that makes a difference, though I could conceivably do it on my Linux box if I had to.

And yes, these are my files and I know the password, no cracker worries here :)

Thanks!

Comment: Flipping switches is off topic on stackoverflow, unless the flipped switches are under the keys of your keyboard and you have selected your favorite IDE or editor.

Comment: I hope your password is pretty strong, as offline attacks are possible for encrypted files, i.e. you are up against brute force and dictionary attacks and computers have become very fast.